# how to delete the particular polygon in google maps add event listener right click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm new to google maps api , I have more polygons in my map, i try to delete the particular polygon in google maps using add event listener right click options, here is my code. while clicking particular polygon not able `setMap(NULL)`;

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places&sensor=true"></script>

<script>
function initialize() {
   alert("ok");
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(24.4799425,73.0934957),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),  mapOptions);
    var arr = new Array();
    var polygons = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var coordinates = [];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker;
    var getBounds;

    // downloadUrl("subdivision-coordinates.php", function(data) {
        //var xmlString = $('#xml_values').val();
        var xmlString ="<subdivisions><subdivision name='Madivala'><coord lat='12.920496072962534' lng='77.6198673248291' id='6' /><coord lat='12.92409332232521' lng='77.62896537780762' id='6' /><coord lat='12.927439554274295' lng='77.6209831237793' id='6' /><coord lat='12.923340413955895' lng='77.61634826660156' id='6' /><coord lat='12.92066338803538' lng='77.61960983276367' id='6' /></subdivision><subdivision name='Sarjapur'><coord lat='12.91706608927013' lng='77.62372970581055' id='7' /><coord lat='12.9158948645401' lng='77.6389217376709' id='7' /><coord lat='12.919659495917085' lng='77.64299869537354' id='7' /><coord lat='12.92409332232521' lng='77.64793395996094' id='7' /><coord lat='12.92480440036714' lng='77.63424396514893' id='7' /><coord lat='12.920998017844783' lng='77.62089729309082' id='7' /></subdivision><subdivision name='Domulur'><coord lat='12.967758119178917' lng='77.63282775878906' id='8' /><coord lat='12.962237705403682' lng='77.65179634094238' id='8' /><coord lat='12.950025446093244' lng='77.64226913452148' id='8' /><coord lat='12.963826927981351' lng='77.6308536529541' id='8' /><coord lat='12.967507193936736' lng='77.63299942016602' id='8' /></subdivision><subdivision name='Indira Nagar'><coord lat='12.982227713276773' lng='77.63505935668945' id='9' /><coord lat='12.985154985380868' lng='77.64518737792969' id='9' /><coord lat='12.965834352522322' lng='77.64904975891113' id='9' /><coord lat='12.965834352522322' lng='77.63694763183594' id='9' /><coord lat='12.982060439543622' lng='77.63497352600098' id='9' /></subdivision><subdivision name='Mariyapan Palya'><coord lat='12.97846402705198' lng='77.54322052001953' id='10' /><coord lat='12.9792167688559' lng='77.56536483764648' id='10' /><coord lat='12.95671716919877' lng='77.56914138793945' id='10' /><coord lat='12.956298941771568' lng='77.54373550415039' id='10' /></subdivision></subdivisions>";
        var xml = xmlParse(xmlString);
        var subdivision = xml.getElementsByTagName("subdivision");
        for (var i = 0; i < subdivision.length; i++) {
            arr = [];
            var coordinates = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("subdivision")[i].getElementsByTagName("coord");
            //console.log("coordinates="+xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("subdivision")[i].getElementsByTagName("coord"));


            for (var j=0; j < coordinates.length; j++) {
              arr.push(new google.maps.LatLng(
                    parseFloat(coordinates[j].getAttribute("lat")),
                    parseFloat(coordinates[j].getAttribute("lng"))
              ));

              var idd=coordinates[j].getAttribute("id");  
              bounds.extend(arr[arr.length-1]);

            }

            polygons.push(new google.maps.Polygon({
                id: idd,
                paths: arr,
                strokeColor: '#BA55D3',
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: '#DA70D6',
                fillOpacity: 0.35
            }));
            polygons[polygons.length-1].setMap(map);

            polygons[polygons.length-1].addListener('click', function (event) {
                //alert(this.id);
                  var service_name=$('input[name="map_service"]:checked').val();
                  $('#add_to_qh').val(this.id);
                  $('#loc_edit_page').attr('href',"locality_service_edit.php?geoId="+this.id+"&service="+service_name);
                  $("#myModal").modal();
            });
            polygons[polygons.length-1].addListener('rightclick', function (event) {

                console.log("Need to delete the clicked polygon");
            });


        }

  map.fitBounds(bounds);

          google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
            zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
              center=map.getCenter();

              var bounds1 = map.getBounds();

              var min_lat = bounds1.getSouthWest().lat();
              var min_lng = bounds1.getSouthWest().lng();

              var max_lat = bounds1.getNorthEast().lat();
              var max_lng = bounds1.getNorthEast().lng();

              var nw = new google.maps.LatLng(min_lat, max_lng);
              var se = new google.maps.LatLng(max_lat, min_lng);

              var area22=google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea([bounds1.getNorthEast(),se, bounds1.getSouthWest(), nw]);
              //Area chage meter2 to meter 
              area22 = area22/1000000;


              var min_area = area22-((area22*20)/100);
              var max_area = area22+((area22*20)/100);

              $('#area').val(area22);

              $('#min_area').val(min_area);
              $('#max_area').val(max_area);

              $('#min_lat').val(min_lat);
              $('#max_lat').val(max_lat);
              $('#min_lng').val(min_lng);
              $('#max_lng').val(max_lng);

              //console.log("Zoommmmmm   my area="+area+" Min Area="+min_area+ " Max Area="+max_area);
           });


}

/**
 * Parses the given XML string and returns the parsed document in a
 * DOM data structure. This function will return an empty DOM node if
 * XML parsing is not supported in this browser.
 * @param {string} str XML string.
 * @return {Element|Document} DOM.
 */
function xmlParse(str) {
  if (typeof ActiveXObject != 'undefined' && typeof GetObject != 'undefined') {
    var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
    doc.loadXML(str);
    return doc;
  }

  if (typeof DOMParser != 'undefined') {
    return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
  }

  return createElement('div', null);
}

$(function(){
initialize();
});

</script>

     <div id="map-canvas" style="height:620px;" ></div>

how to delete the particular polygon in google maps add event listener right click
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete the polygon, add an additional property [auto_id] to identify the polygon, e.g.

```
        polygons.push(new google.maps.Polygon({
            auto_id:i,
            id: idd,
            paths: arr,
            strokeColor: '#BA55D3',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#DA70D6',
            fillOpacity: 0.35
        }));

        polygons[polygons.length-1].addListener('rightclick', function (event) {
           polygons[this.auto_id].setMap(null);
        });
```